# Getting Dataframe from existing Dataframe after some filter

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a Data frame something like this.

```
Aman Aggarwal      Amar Jannela   Vipin Kumar       Roshan Pati
BlackBuck          DJ CHETAS      WOW Editions      MensXP
Transport/Freight  Musician/Band  Furniture         News/Media Website
Like               Like           Like              Like
NaN                NaN            NaN               NaN   
GiveMeSport        NaN            500 Startups      No Abuse KG
News/Media Website Celina Jaitly  Internet/Software Community
Like               Actor/Director Like              Liked
NaN                Like           NaN               NaN
NaN                NaN            Jitendra Kumar    Monogatari Series
Anushka Sharma     Durjoy Datta   Actor/Director    TV Show
Actor/Director     Author         Liked             Like
Like               Like           NaN               NaN
NaN                NaN            NaN               NaN
```

Obviously NaN are empty rows in original csv file. I have to extract two data frames from this.Column name as first element of every row in new datafra and page_name(BlackBuck) element of that column as further element of respective rows. Something like this.

```
Aman Aggarwal     BlackBuck        GiveMeSport    Anushka Sharma 
Amar Jannela      DJ CHETAS        Celina Jaitly  Durjoy Datta 
Vipin Kumar       WOW Editions     500 Startups   Jitendra Kumar
Roshan Pati       MensXP           No Abuse KGP   Monogatari Series
```

2nd dataframe also similar like this

```
Aman Aggarwal   Transport/Freight  News/Media Website  Actor/Director
Amar Jannela       Musician/Band      Actor/Director          Author
Vipin Kumar           Furniture   Internet/Software  Actor/Director
Roshan Pati  News/Media Website           Community         TV Show
```

The real issue is that there is arbitrary NaN values some where ank may be like/liked too but only thing is that name(BlackBuck) and category(Transport/Freight) are together.Since my coe cant identify which is page_name and which is category. So probably I have to remove NaN value and 'Like' and 'Liked'  separately for each column first and then aligned accordingly and transpose. How to this efficiently in python2.7.

Comment: @jezrael  any help on this too??

Comment: How do you know when there is a new page name? Is it before a `Like`, or after a `NaN`? What's the logic?

Comment: @IanS sequence is something like this that first comes my page name and then category. I need to remove NaN and "Like","Liked" desperately for each column and then my alternate row will represent page name and page category . I can simply transpose the dataframe then. I have written a code which works fine but is quite inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will obviously have to do it column by column, as the names and categories are not aligned. I use `apply` to work column by column, and filter out values that are either null or in the list of strings to avoid:

```
filter = ['Like', 'Liked']

df.apply(lambda column: 
    column[~(column.isnull() | column.isin(filter))].reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Note that this would also work, but I don't quite trust it:

```
import numpy as np
filter = [np.nan, 'Like', 'Liked']

df.apply(lambda column: column[~column.isin(filter)].reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
        Aman Aggarwal    Amar Jannela        Vipin Kumar         Roshan Pati
0           BlackBuck       DJ CHETAS       WOW Editions              MensXP
1   Transport/Freight   Musician/Band          Furniture  News/Media Website
2         GiveMeSport   Celina Jaitly       500 Startups         No Abuse KG
3  News/Media Website  Actor/Director  Internet/Software           Community
4      Anushka Sharma    Durjoy Datta     Jitendra Kumar   Monogatari Series
5      Actor/Director          Author     Actor/Director             TV Show
```

**Notes**

- It is important to test `column.isnull()` before `column.str.contains('Like')` otherwise the latter will fail on null values.
- You need to reset the index otherwise the results will be aligned on the original index, which is exactly what you do not want.

Comment: There are 2-3 strings which are random not just 'Like'  and yes thanks for extra notes i faced those issue while applying my 'inefficient code'

Comment: I'd be curious to see performance comparisons. Don't forget to accept my answer if it helped you, I'm eager to cross the 2,000 reputation threshold ;)

Comment: I think it will work, I will try it later coz files are on different system, but you didnt tell me about how to add extra strings('Liked') which are needed to be removed. simply adding will work or i will have to make list.

Comment: Well here `str.contains('Like')` will also remove `'Liked'`, as one is contained in the other. Are there other strings?

Comment: Yes let say one more string 'XYZ' is there.There are around 4 strings.

Comment: and this way will remove page names which contains like. So it would be better to remove exact 'Like' and 'Liked' e.t.c

Comment: @ranadan just now actually :)